# Navigator Wouldn't Navigate to the corresponding Screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting push notifications from `Firebase`. Notifications are being received properly. What I'm trying to do is to redirect user to some specific screens but `Navigator` wouldn't navigate. When in background, app Navigates to the main screen when tapped on the Notification. I tried whatever solutions are already suggested on stack overflow but none worked for me. Here is the code I'm currently at:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Initializing Firebase and Getting Values
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ).whenComplete(() {
    print('Firebase Initialized');
  });
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  //initialising firebase message plugin
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  // function to request notifications permissions
  void requestNotificationPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: true,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: true,
        criticalAlert: true,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true
    );
    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('user granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('user granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      // AppSettings.openNotificationSettings();
      print('user denied permission');
    }
  }

  void initLocalNotifications(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
    var androidInitializationSettings = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iosInitializationSettings = const DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSetting = InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitializationSettings,
        iOS: iosInitializationSettings);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSetting,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {
          // handle interaction
          handleMessageiOS(context);
        });
  }

  void firebaseInit() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("notifications title:${message.notification!.title}");
        print("notifications body:${message.notification!.body}");
      }
      if (Platform.isIOS){
         foregroundMessage();
         handleMessageiOS(context);
        // initLocalNotifications(context, message);
      }
    });
  }

  // // function to show visible notification when app is active
  // Future<void> showNotification(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
  //   const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
  //   DarwinNotificationDetails(presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);
  //   NotificationDetails notificationDetails = const NotificationDetails(iOS: darwinNotificationDetails);
  //   Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
  //     flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  //         0,
  //         message.notification!.title.toString(),
  //         message.notification!.body.toString(),
  //         notificationDetails);
  //   });
  // }

  //function to get device token on which we will send the notifications
  Future<String> getDeviceToken() async {
    String? token = await messaging.getToken();
    return token!;
  }

  void isTokenRefresh() async {
    messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
      event.toString();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        // print('refresh');
      }
    });
  }

  //handle tap on notification when app is in background or terminated
  Future<void> setupInteractMessage(context) async {
    // when app is terminated
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
       handleMessageiOS(context);
    }
    //when app is opened
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      handleMessageiOS(context);
    });
  }

// If don't use SchedulerBinding Navigator gives error
// If used SchedulerBinding, Navigator isn't triggered at all

   handleMessageiOS(context){
    print('Message From handleMessageiOS');
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      print('Triggering Navigator');
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LayoutScreen(layoutIndex: 1, selectedPage: 1,)));
    });
  }

  Future foregroundMessage() async{
    // print('From foreground Message');
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

@override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  requestNotificationPermission();
  firebaseInit();
  getDeviceToken().then((value) {print('Device Token: $value');});
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {.....}
```